# Image display error in function call with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to display an image using the code below which is contained in a function call.

```
myWindow.document.write("<center><img border='2' src='../images/autumn/0216.jpg' width='120' height='90' /></center>");
```

This works fine when you explicitly set the src details e.g. `src = '../images/autumn/0216.jpg'` and the image is displayed correctly. What I need to do is send the url of the image to the function so I can display whatever image is required (this is the 'photo' reference in the function name). The function name is as follows:

```
function photoorder(category, reference, photo)
```

I have tried sending the image url `'../images/autumn/0216.jpg'` to the function call, it is received and formatted correctly. But when I use the command `src = photo` the image is not displayed. e.g.

```
myWindow.document.write("<center><img border='2' src='photo' width='120' height='90' /></center>");
```

or

```
myWindow.document.write("<center><img border='2' src=photo width='120' height='90' /></center>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myWindow.document.write("<center><img border='2' src='" + photo + "' width='120' height='90' /></center>");
```

Comment: That works fine. Thank you very much.This is the only combination I had not tried.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose is advisable to use jQuery...

but in your function photoorder(...) photo is a param like "../images/autumn/0216.jpg" ?

the you should use:

```
myWindow.document.write("<center><img border='2' src='" + photo + "' width='120' height='90' /></center>");
```